# Ruby on Rails, create an instance variable from another instance variable's property

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instance-variables

I think this is an easy question but I can't seem to wrap my head around it to solve it. I want to create an instance variable from a property of another instance variable.
For example:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ['day > ?', Date.today], :order => 'day')
```

I want to get another instance variable that contains all of the dates from the `@posts`. Is there a way of quickly getting it without having to create a helper/function? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@posts.map(&:day)
```

which is a shorthand for

```
@posts.map do |post|
  post.day
end
```

The result is an array of the value of each post.day

Comment: Thanks, it's been great to me so far =)

Answer (score 0):

What Wayne has is a appropriate. I prefer collect instead of map, but they are equivalent.

```
@dates = @posts.collect{|post| post.day}.uniq
```

Notice, uniq at the end will give you the unique values.